# This is returning false

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop, mysqli

```
if($stmt = $this->Sys->db->prepare("INSERT INTO dj_videos (title, url, caption) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {

        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $title, $url, $comment);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->fetch();

        if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {

            return TRUE;

        }
        else {

            return FALSE;

        }
```

This is returning false but it inserts the information into the database everytime. It blows my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**mysqli_stmt::execute**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
So you only need to return the result of it:

```
if($stmt = $this->Sys->db->prepare("INSERT INTO dj_videos (title, url, caption) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $title, $url, $comment);
    return $stmt->execute();
}
```

By the way,　if the statement is `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `INSERT`, the total number of affected rows can be determined by using the `mysqli_stmt_affected_rows()` function.

Answer (score 0):

`num_rows` returns the number of rows in a statement result set.

You want [`affected_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php), which returns the number of rows changed, deleted, or inserted by the last executed statement

```
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $title, $url, $comment);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->fetch();

    if($stmt->affected_rows == 1) {

        return TRUE;

    }
    else {

        return FALSE;

    }
```